# Cursor missing in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, mouse, touchpad, cursor

So when I start up my laptop the cursor will appear for like a second on the login screen and then disappear totally. I have a Lenovo P50s.

When I did `less /proc/bus/input/devices` the Synaptics pointing device and IBM trackpoint devices were both listed.

Last night a similar thing happened except the cursor was still visible, it just wouldn't move. I fixed it temporarily by doing `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and restarting the machine. The mouse then worked fine for the rest of the night and today until now.

Comment: What is the output of *sudo xinput list*

Comment: It actually started working again randomly, so the xinput list looks normal now. At this point I'm convinced that this is hardware issue so I'm just gonna get some compressed air and clean out the machine as best as I can.